# Grails - Data Segregation hierarchy

Tags: grails

I am relatively new to grails and am trying to decide how it is possible to implement a security / data segregation requirement...

The users of the application will have one of three levels of access:

STUDENT - should be able to only see data specific to themselves

TEACHER - should be able to see data for all students in their class

SENIORTEACHER - should be able to see data for all students in classes taught by teachers that report to them.

An example hierarchy is shown below:

- SENIORTEACHER1

  - TEACHER1

    - STUDENT1
    - STUDENT2
  - TEACHER2

    - STUDENT3
- SENIORTEACHER2

  - TEACHER3

    - STUDENT4
    - STUDENT5

Is anyone able to recommend how I could approach this requirement with a grails app? I've looked at the multi-tenant-single-db plugin but it seems this does not support the hierarchy access that I need.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

[Grails Spring Security Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/14%20Hierarchical%20Roles.html) handles this case pretty easily, and even if it needs a bit of practice to be fully used, it's a no-brainer between using this professionnally-crafted librairy and starting such a solution from scratch (it could be a great exercise, though)